# Set cookie from API response in React

Tags: reactjs, authentication, session-cookies

I have a React app, and an API. When i `POST` data to APIs login url API responses me back with cookie on successful login, which I have to set, so in each next request user will send this cookie. But I can't find a method to get it from response. [image]

I want to set `sessionid`, but I can't reach it within code. I tried to do

```
Cookies.set('sessionid', response.headers['sessionid']);
```

But it sets `undefined`. `console.log(response.headers)` also gives me `{content-length: "31", content-type: "application/json"}`. Do I do something wrong?

Sender function:

```
formSender() {
    const url_to_send = `${this.state.api_base_url}:${this.state.api_base_port}${this.state.api_user_url}/login/`;
    axios.post(url_to_send, `username=${this.state.username}&password=${this.state.password}`, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})
        .then((response) => {
        // I need to set the cookie here
            this.setState({
                login_success: response.status === 200,
                request_sent: false
            });
        })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set Access-Control-Expose-Headers in the back end or

```
await axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: YOUR_URL,
                data: Data,  
                headers: { 'Authorization': 'TOKEN' }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problems and i do that for resolve in backend:

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: true,
    credentials: true
}));
```

and the axios request :

```
 axios({
    method: "post",
    url: `http://localhost:5500/api/user/login`,
    withCredentials: true,
    data: {
      email,
      password,
    },
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      }
  })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I was initially looking for a solution to setting a cookie from a response, but I realized if it's passed as a Set-Cookie header then it is set by the browser. No need to set it manually. [Here is the console view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ouw0.png)

My app looks something like this:

```js
const app = express();

app.use(cors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
    methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'OPTIONS', 'HEAD'],
    credentials: true,
}))

app.use(cookieParser())


app.get('/foo', verifyToken, (req, res) => { 
// you can omit verifyToken if you want, it's for bearer auth.
    if (true) {
        res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', 'example')
        res.send('Welcome')
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(403);
    }
});
```

The React side:

```js
<Button onClick={() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8081/foo', {
        params: {},
        headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer 123`,
                // again, omit ^ if you're not doing bearer auth
        },
        withCredentials: true,
    }
    ).then((response) => {
        console.log('cookie should be set')
    })
}}>Express cookie</Button>
```

Bear in mind if you're deploying to a server both react and express should be on an https connection. Connecting http <-> https causes other issues with cookies.